# Return just the first result of mysql Query

Tags: mysql, database, limit

In one of my applications, I have to determine if '`foo_id`' is present in the '`foo`' column of a table '`foo_table`'.

*My requirements will be met as soon as I know there is one such '`foo_id`' present.*
Now, my question is how to restrict this to the first match.

When I checked these queries against `mySql EXPLAIN`:

```
- select count(foo) from foo_table where foo=<foo_id>;
- select foo from foo_table where foo=<foo_id> limit 1;
```

In both of the cases, the number of rows was 58.
Is there a way in mySql such that I can restrict the number of rows to 1 (the first match), such that rows are not touched unnecessarily (because I don't need that).

Comment: Are you sure "select foo from foo_table where foo=<foo_id> limit 1;
" gives you 58 rows?

Comment: yes, at least the 'rows' column via "explain select foo from foo_table where foo=<foo_id> limit 1;" showed 58.

Comment: don't see `EXPLAIN` just execute the query

Answer (score 13, accepted):

explain plan will always show 58, because is number of records which match you criteria.

However LIMIT 1 is all you need.

Comment: Okay. Does it mean that when I actually execute the query, only 1 row will be touched?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EXISTS` as such:

`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM foo_table WHERE foo=<foo_id>)`.

The SELECT is ignored as EXISTS only checks the WHERE clause. As it is good practice to avoid using `*`, it is substituted by `1` here.

Here is the [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html).

Comment: This still shows the same number of rows that match the criteria in `EXPLAIN`, but it is preferred to `LIMIT 1` for checking if a row exists.

Answer (score 0):

`LIMIT 1` is the way to go, so you already found the solution yourself:

```
SELECT 1 FROM foo_table WHERE foo = ? LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `explain` MySQL statement shows total # of rows instead of what you specify in Limit:

```
explain select foo from foo_table where foo=<foo_id> limit 1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | foo_table   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    58 |       | 
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```